Spring ssl bundle support for Encrypted RSA private keys
I am using spring ssl bundles for PEM certificate and private key.
spring:
  ssl:
    bundle:
      pem:
        server:
          key:
            alias: "my-alias"
          keystore:
            private-key-password: password
            private-key: private.key
            certificate: cert.pem

I have an encrypted private key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,9d796f1112cd463fc171a70a484703e7

When starting app, I get exception below:

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:165) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:619) ~[spring-context-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:335) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1363) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1352) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at com.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:10) ~[!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:91) ~[test-certificate.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:53) ~[test-certificate.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.launch.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58) ~[test-certificate.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jettyServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Error creating bean with name 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'sslBundleRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/SslAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.ssl.DefaultSslBundleRegistry]: Factory method 'sslBundleRegistry' threw exception with message: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:607) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:223) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:186) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'sslBundleRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/SslAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.ssl.DefaultSslBundleRegistry]: Factory method 'sslBundleRegistry' threw exception with message: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:665) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getWebServerFactoryCustomizerBeans(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.getCustomizers(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:78) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:70) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:58) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1798) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryCustomizer]: Factory method 'servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'sslBundleRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/SslAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.ssl.DefaultSslBundleRegistry]: Factory method 'sslBundleRegistry' threw exception with message: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sslBundleRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/ssl/SslAutoConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.ssl.DefaultSslBundleRegistry]: Factory method 'sslBundleRegistry' threw exception with message: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:648) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:636) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory$DependencyObjectProvider.getIfAvailable(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:2112) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.servletWebServerFactoryCustomizer(ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration.java:81) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.ssl.DefaultSslBundleRegistry]: Factory method 'sslBundleRegistry' threw exception with message: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:178) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:644) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register SSL bundle 'server'
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.lambda$registerBundles$2(SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.java:69) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.registerBundles(SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.java:58) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.registerBundles(SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.java:52) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration.lambda$sslBundleRegistry$0(SslAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$RefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:395) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:261) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Sink$ChainedReference.end(Sink.java:261) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslAutoConfiguration.sslBundleRegistry(SslAutoConfiguration.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:146) ~[spring-beans-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing private key or unrecognized format
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemPrivateKeyParser.parse(PemPrivateKeyParser.java:216) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemContent.getPrivateKey(PemContent.java:83) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.LoadedPemSslStore.loadPrivateKey(LoadedPemSslStore.java:72) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.LoadedPemSslStore.lambda$new$1(LoadedPemSslStore.java:49) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier$1.getWithException(ThrowingSupplier.java:80) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier$1.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:84) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.util.function.SingletonSupplier.get(SingletonSupplier.java:106) ~[spring-core-6.1.11.jar!/:6.1.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.LoadedPemSslStore.privateKey(LoadedPemSslStore.java:97) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.ssl.pem.PemSslStore.withAlias(PemSslStore.java:77) ~[spring-boot-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.PropertiesSslBundle.get(PropertiesSslBundle.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.lambda$registerBundles$0(SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.java:59) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ssl.SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.lambda$registerBundles$2(SslPropertiesBundleRegistrar.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.3.2.jar!/:3.3.2]
    ... 75 common frames omitted




After some debug, I saw that spring uses PemPrivateKeyParser.java with pattern PKCS1_RSA_HEADER, which match the beginning of the file, but it doesn't match the rest of the private key file - due to those 2 headers. (All other patterns are also not match)
How can I use this kind of private keys with spring ssl bundles?

My whirlwind tour of the source code and the documentation suggests that encrypted PKCS1 RSA private keys are not supported, but encrypted PKCS8 private keys are. Regardless of the exact details, just convert your keys to a supported format.

The comment from @President James K Polk above is correct. Encrypted PKCS#8 private keys are supported, encrypted PKCS#1 (and EC) keys are not supported.
You should be able to convert the PKCS#1 key to PKCS#8 with a command like this:
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in private.key -out new-private.key


Thanx all.
Converting the private key indeed worked, but only when I converted it manually.
Since I was needed to do it automatically (using script on startup) - I couldn't make it since I didn't found a way to call this command and provide the password as the command argument/parameter.
But - I finally managed to have a solution: I converted the certificate and the private key to p12 file and then spring ssl bundle works fine without need to decrypt it first. Apparently the problem exist only when I declare a spring ssl PEM bundle.
